# How to create a table in MySQL 5.5 that has fulltext indexing and partitioning?

Tags: mysql, partitioning, full-text-search, create-table, mysql-error-1214

I update MySQL versition from 5.0 to 5.5. and I am new for studying `mysql partition`. firstly, I type:

> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE  '%partition%'

```
Variable_name      Value
have_partitioning   YES
```

Make sure that the new version support `partition`. I tried to partition my table by every 10 minutes, then INSERT, UPDATE, QUERY huge data into this table for a test.

First, I need create a new table, I type my code:

```
CREATE TABLE test  ( 
`id` int unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, 
`words` varchar(100) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,  
`date` varchar(10) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),  
FULLTEXT KEY `index` (`words`)
) 
ENGINE=MyISAM  
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci 
AUTO_INCREMENT=0  
PARTITION BY RANGE (MINUTE(`date`)) 
(
PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (1322644000),  
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (1322644600) , 
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (1322641200) ,  
PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (1322641800) ,  
PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

It return alert: `#1564 - This partition function is not allowed`, so what is this problem? thanks.

**UPDATE**

Modify `date` into `int NOT NULL`, and `PARTITION BY RANGE MINUTE(date)` into `PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(date)`

```
CREATE TABLE test  ( 
`id` int unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, 
`words` varchar(100) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,  
`date` int NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),  
FULLTEXT KEY `index` (`words`)
) 
ENGINE=MyISAM  
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci 
AUTO_INCREMENT=0  
PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(`date`) 
(
PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (1322644000),  
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (1322644600) , 
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (1322641200) ,  
PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (1322641800) ,  
PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

Then caused new error: `#1214 - The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am so sorry, mysql not support fulltext and partition at the same time.

See [partitioning limitations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-limitations.html)

**FULLTEXT indexes.**  Partitioned tables do not support FULLTEXT indexes or searches. This includes partitioned tables employing the MyISAM storage engine.

Answer (score 0):

One issue might be

`select MINUTE('2008-10-10 56:56:98')` returns null, the reason is `Minute` function returns minute from time or datetime value, where as in your case date is varchar

Comment: Rahul, so do you think, what is the best way for my insert code? I wish partition my table by every 10 minutes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

`MINUTE` function returns in either date/datetime expression. Again, A partitioning key must be either an integer column or an expression that resolves to an
integer but inyour case it's VARCHAR

Comment: Zohaib, I update my code, but this time caused `#1214 - The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes`.  do you have any idea?